# Office365 API: get current user email using oauth2 token?

Tags: office365, office365api

I'm working on authentication for Outlook (office365) users in our web app through ouath2. Mainly I was followed this example: https://dev.outlook.com/RestGettingStarted/Tutorial/python . I managed to get response with `access_token` in it; also article from the link above, states that response should contain `token_id` which in turn will contain encoded user email. In my case response with access token is something like this:

```
{
u'token_type': u'Bearer', 
u'scope': u'https://outlook.office.com/mail.readwrite', 
u'access_token': u'EwB4Aul3BAA...ZQE=', 
u'expires_in': u'3600'
}
```

Apparently no `token_id` here. I've googled a bit for some Office365 API which will allow to fetch user info (and email) using `access_token` but no luck.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the answer is pretty simple: I forget to add `openid` to scopes before requesting access token.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the PHP example at https://dev.outlook.com/RestGettingStarted/Tutorial/php

However, I was unable to get the email address of the signed in user, even with the **openid** scope.

After about 24 hours of searching and testing, I eventually found that I needed to add **profile** as a scope.  I only discovered this via the OAuth Sandbox https://oauthplay.azurewebsites.net/ by examining request headers.

Hopefully, this helps someone.

This really should be better documented.